# Display a new entry modal when clicking on a relation field

Tags: plugin-development, matrix, relations

For a complex website we have nested a relation field inside a matrix.

It makes little sense for us to show the list of already created entries so we would prefer to directly display the new entry modal when clicking on a relation field. Our goal is to facilitate the editors lives and thus avoid multiple modal nesting... (See below).

Thank you in advance for your advice. Peace.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd rather look into nesting Super Table fields within your Matrix block types than relating Entries. The Entry element type and its relationship field come with a lot of inappropriate UI for the use case you're trying to solve.

Another approach would be to write a plugin that provides its own element type and relationship field / modal UI.